# how to display an object on jsp page?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

i m pretty new to Spring MVC, i m trying to setup a page to display user information

I have trouble with the controler and the view.

Controler (getDetail returns a User object, it has an email field) :

```
 @RequestMapping("/{code}")
 public String get(@PathVariable long code,ModelMap model) throws Exception {
  model.addAttribute("user",simpleUserManager.getDetail(code));
  return "userdetail";
 }
```

in userdetail.jsp :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

<html>
  <head><title><fmt:message key="title"/></title></head>
  <body>
User Detail :
${user.email}
  </body>
</html>
```

But i get this error when i go on the page :

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute value must not be null
```

I am using Spring 3, on Tomcat6

So i hope you can tell me what i am doing wrong ...

Thank you

Comment: Can you make sure that `simpleUserManager.getDetail(code)` is not returning null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ModelMap.addAttribute()` does not permit the attribute value to be `null`, and will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it is.

Your controller needs to check whether the result of `simpleUserManager.getDetail(code)` returns a `null`, and only try and render the result if it's not. If it *is* `null`, you need to do something appropriate to that situation.

Comment: and what is the best way to handle null object in the controler? should i redirect to another page with an error message on it? or create an empty user and handle this in the JSP ? to check for empty ID and display error message...

Comment: @guigui42: That's entirely up to you, and what makes sense for your application. Simplest thing would be to return the name of an error JSP, instead of the `userdetail`.

Comment: I created an error.jsp and changed the code to if (!usr.equals(null)) {
   model.addAttribute("user",usr);
   return "userdetail";
  }
  else {
   model.addAttribute("error","User does not exist !!!");
   return "error";
  }, but i still get  NullPointerException when the user doesnt exist